# For two quasi-isometric Riemannian metrics on a non-compact manifold, can I bound connected components of the set of points where bi-Lipschitz fails?

Tags: metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry

Let $g_1,g_2$ be Riemannian metrics on a non-compact manifold $M$ such that $d_1,d_2$ are their distance functions respectively.
They are quasi-isometric if there exist constants $A\geq 1,B\geq 0$ such that
$$\frac{1}{A}d_1(x,y)-B<d_2(x,y)<Ad_1(x,y)+B$$
for all $x,y\in M$.

If $B=0$, they are bi-Lipschitz.
What I want to ask is that when $g_1,g_2$ are quasi-isometric but not bi-Lipschitz,
can I control the set $F_C$, which is the set of points where local bi-Lipschitz fails with respect to $C>A$, defined as
$$F_C:=\{x\in M|g_1(u,v)>Cg_2(u,v) \text{ or } g_1(u,v)<\frac{1}{C}g_2(u,v)\text{ for some }u,v\in T_xM\}$$
For sufficiently large $C$?
If each connected component of $F_C$ is contained in some compact set, it would be great.

Motive of this question is that when two metrics are bi-Lipschitz, we can make them quasi-isometric but not bi-Lipschitz by changing one of two metrics. To do so, we can 'make balloons' like the following figure:
[image]
which is altering the metric within compact sets while the resulting set is uniformly bounded.
I want the converse of this, but weaker statement or some properties of $F_C$ would also be very helpful.

Comment: Think of the following example: One metric is the product $S^1\times {\mathbb R}$. The other metric is obtained by gluing two hyperbolic cusps ("tractroid") and smoothing it out along the rim.

Comment: @MoisheKohan What if other conditions are added? For example, curvature is bounded above and injectivity radius is bounded away from zero.

Comment: Probably not enough either even if you additionally assume negative curvature.